# How to check if a button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, nightmare

Hello I have the following code:

```
async function pressNext(nightmare) {
    const check = await check_nextButton(nightmare);
    const disabled= await check_disabled();
    if(check&&disabled) {
        await nightmare.click('#example_next');
        await extractInfo(nightmare);
        return pressNext(nightmare);
    }
    return null;
}
```

It is supposed to click the next button on a table as long as it exists , the problem is that the button exists even after it becomes disabled, so I can't think of any way to check if the "next button" is disabled 
The check disabled function is just something I've tried but didn't work , so I need to somehow make that function be true only if the `#example_next` is not disabled
EDIT:
[image of Next enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cixWq.png)

[image of Next disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niV9X.png)

I tried comparing the classNames and that doesn't work

Comment: `if(element.disabled) { /* do something */ }`?

Comment: I'm using nightmareJS

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.disabled`:

```
if(!your_button.disabled){ //if not disabled
    # Do something
} else {
    # Do something
}
```

Comment: Op isn't using jQuery but NightmareJS

Comment: Yeah I do know that but using nightmare , Do i select my button in nightmare.evaluate and then i return it and then check the actual disability?

Answer (score 0):

So I've fixed it guys , I've made a function that fixes it , verifying if the selector for the disabled class exists , i the folllowing

```
async function check_disabled(nightmare){
   return nightmare.exists('.paginate_button.next.disabled');

}
```